# Why is Jing's video quality inferior when uploaded to YouTube?

Tags: video, youtube, screencasts

I just got a PRO edition of [JING](http://www.jingproject.com/pro/), and uploaded my screencast to [YouTube](http://YouTube.com). What can I say, the quality is really BAD. I've followed YouTube guidelines for resolution (1280 x 720), but I can't tell any text on my screencast on YouTube.

Screencast.com (Jing's website) shows the video in original quality, but you can use all that functionality for free.

Any suggesions on making my screencast's quality better on YouTube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot make the quality better, decrease the resolution slightly, or increase the size of your fonts used to increase visibility, other then that I don't really know what to add!

Answer (score 1):

Compression is a natural enemy of Text. Particularly if the text is small. As SevenT2 suggested you should increase the size of your text to make it readable after YouTube compresses it.

You will notice that most YouTube videos wisely fill almost the whole screen with large text, to ensure that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Because every video you upload on YouTube is re-transcoded again.